# Find max value of JSON and store as a variable

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a d3 graph which specifies the range on the Y axis like this:

```
  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1]) // input 
    .range([height, 0]); // output
```

However a scale of 0 to 1 isn't very useful. I want it to work out what is a suitable range for me. I'm a bit new to this so I thought if I did something like this:

```
// Data
var dataset = [{
      y: 0.1
    },
    {
      y: 0.6
    },
        {
      y: 0.6
    },
    {
      y: 0.7
    }
  ];

var mymax = Math.max(dataset);
```

Then I can find the maximum value in my dataset, and then feed that into my .domain range like this:

```
.domain([0, mymax]) // input
```

However, I appreciate my attempt at this is wrong because I get NaN returned. I think it might be pointing at the letter Y and not my numbers.

I don't feel like this is a duplicate of the question.

Comment: @gerardo-furtado - This is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @x-ray You are correct, I thought OP was asking how to use `d3.max` here, I mistook `max` for `d3.max`. I just reopened it.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Just out of interest, why is d3.max not the right thing here?

Comment: @Jimmy Unlike `Math.max`, `d3.max` accepts an array. Actually `d3.max` is the best choice here, just using the accessor to specify the property.

Comment: Without knowing what d3.max does, that's not the point here. The point is that you asked about Math.max(), and the question that was referenced as a duplicate was about d3.max, not Math.max().

Comment: He asked just *out of interest*, as he said. Also, I already said that I misread it, and I already reopened the question. Can we just move on?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I want to add that closing questions as duplicates while referencing discussions that do not fit to the question is really frustrating - both for the one that asked and the ones that want to answer. I have seen that happen here on SO multiple times. It would have been of much more use if you would have commented about using d3.max instead of Math.max in the first place rather than closing this question.

Comment: @x-ray again: I misread it. I'll be of much more use if I ignore S.O. for a while, as I'll do starting now.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks for the info :)

Comment: It would reduce the number of needless questions if the OP's do a normal search, for things like you this you get a lot of hits, search with the Big Search, SO search is not as good. And reading the **docs**  is also very helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mymax = Math.max.apply(Math, dataset.map(function(o) { return o.y; }));
```

Comment: This is a correct answer to how to find the maximum value in the given datastructure. I do not know why somebody downvoted this. If you can use arrow functions, you can shorten it to `var mymax = Math.max.apply(Math, dataset.map(o => o.y);`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: To add an explanation: [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) expects multiple function parameters, so you need to call it e.g. like this: `Math.max(0.1, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7);`. You can convert your array of objects to an array of numbers with [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which for the given example returns `[0.1, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7]`.

Comment: This can then be used with [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Comment: Stupid that I have to type the answer here because someone incorrectly marked this as duplicate. (Probably similar questions have been asked before, but it is definitely not a duplicate of the referenced question.)

Comment: @x-ray we may never know why someone downvoted it until the downvoter explains himself/herself, but a one-line answer without any explanation at all is not exactly something that deserves 3 upvotes.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado If you wouldn't have closed the question someone could have given a more elaborate answer. But as you stated above - we should just move on now.

Comment: @x-ray The fact that I closed the question - for which I already said 1k times that it was a mistake and I already apologised for it - has nothing to do with this answerer writing a one-liner and someone downvoting it. I was simply replying your comment *"I do not know why somebody downvoted this"*, which was clearly a mistake that I regret as well.

Comment: my mistake that i have not explained it. by the way @x-ray good job you explain it very well :)